# Bithack for: if x is 0, then x should be -1, else x should be untouched

Tags: c, int, bit-manipulation

What is the quickest bit-hack to achieve the following result?

Let x be a 4 byte int, in a C program.

If x is `0x00000000`, then x should be `0xFFFFFFFF`, else x should be untouched.

Comment: A simple `if` is not good enough for you?

Comment: It will be very hard to produce code which is more readable and efficient than `if(x == 0) { x = 0xFFFFFFFF; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `x |= -(x == 0);`
- `x |= -!x;`
- `x = x ? x : 0xFFFFFFFF;`
- `if (x == 0)
       x = 0xFFFFFFFF;`

  ...

Benchmark and choose what's appropriate for you

Comment: That should be **x =** 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: On two's complement systems, you can also use `x -= !x;`

Comment: @TomKarzes: On non-two's complement systems, -1 is not 0xFFFFFFFF, so if that bit pattern were desired, the qualification would be needed. But the question says that "x should be -1" and `x -= !x` will convert 0 to -1 regardless of representation.

Comment: @rici I was going by the message body rather than the subject line, but taken together, I guess they imply a two's complement representation.